# Django request.POST.get() is empty for field values set by javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I have a html form where user provides length, width and height and there is onkeyup event linked to a javascript function which in return provides volume in a disabled textbox. Now, the values are shown in the textbox and they do change dynamically but when I am submitting the form and accessing it in the **views** using POST method, I am only getting values for input fields which are filled by user and the disabled textbox returns **None**.

I have to store that volume in session and pass it to next view on requested but since the **request.POST.get()** is None, I am not able to retrieve it.

**Note**: I am just using volume calculation as an example to explain the issue.

```
# html

<head>
   <script>
       calcVolume(){
         var Length = Number(document.getElementsByName('length')[0].value);
         var Width = Number(document.getElementsByName('width')[0].value);
         var Height = Number(document.getElementsByName('height')[0].value);
         if (Length != '' && Width != '' && Height != '') {
             var Volume = Length * Width * Height
             document.getElementsByName('volume')[0].value = Volume;
         }
       }
   <script>
</head>    

<form method="POST" action="">
   {csrf_token}
   <table>
     <tr>
     <td><input name="length" onkeyup="calcVolume();"></td>
     <td><input name="width" onkeyup="calcVolume();"></td>
     <td><input name="height" onkeyup="calcVolume();"></td>
     <td><input name="volume" value="0" disabled></td>
     <td><button type="submit">Next</button></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
</form>



# views.py

def vol(request):
   if method.request == "POST":
     request.session['l'] = request.POST['length']
     request.session['w'] = request.POST['width']
     request.session['h'] = request.POST['height']
     request.session['volume'] = request.POST.get('volume')
     print(request.session['volume']) # here the volume is None
     return redirect('/whatever_next_page')
   else:
     return render(request,'calculate_volume.html')
```

Comment: Are you sure that your JS `document.getElementsByName('volume')[0].value = Volume;` is called?

Comment: @Hagyn Yes ! it is being called as it is immediately updating the value in disabled input field, if you happen to change the value any input box, the JS changes the value of the disabled input box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `disabled` formfield is not sent to the server:

> The difference between disabled and readonly is that read-only controls can still function and are still focusable, whereas **disabled controls** can not receive focus and **are not submitted with the form** and generally do not function as controls until they are enabled.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled

By using `readonly` instead of `disabled` your code will probably start working.